# Laplace transform of $\sin(wt)\cdot u(t-t_0)$

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform

I need to find the laplace transform of $\sin(wt)\cdot u(t-t_0)$

The answer is $$\frac{e^{-st_0}}{\sqrt{s^2+w^2}}\cdot \sin\left(wt_0 + \tan^{-1}\frac{w}{s}\right)$$

I tried using the general definition:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(wt)\cdot u(t-t_0)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t=\int_{t_0}^{\infty}\sin(wt)e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t$$

**Edit** : (After seeing @[cesareo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/397348/cesareo)'s final answer, I have corrected minor mathematical mistakes and got the same solution but I still require the above form)

After using: 
$$\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)\,dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\sin(bx)-b\cos(bx)\right)$$

I get:

$$=\frac{e^{-st}}{s^2+w^2}(-s\sin(wt)-w\cos(-st))\Biggr|_{t_0}^{\infty}=\frac{e^{-st_0}}{s^2+w^2}(s\sin(wt_0)+w\cos(-st_0))$$

I am stuck here. I think I will require some trigonometrical reduction but I am not able to figure it out.

**Edit 2:**

I found the final solution by simply using inverse identities:

$$\frac{e^{-st_0}}{s^2+w^2}(s\sin(wt_0)+w\cos(-st_0))=\frac{e^{-st_0}}{\sqrt{s^2+w^2}}\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+w^2}}\sin(wt_0)+\frac{w}{\sqrt{s^2+w^2}}\cos(st_0)\right)$$

Using:
$$\tan^{-1}(\frac ws)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{s^2+w^2}}\right)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{s^2+w^2}}\right)$$

We can get the final answer in terms of arctan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\sin(\omega t)u(t-t_0)\right)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s t}\sin(\omega t)u(t-t_0)dt 
$$

now making the change of variable $\tau = t-t_0$ we have

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\sin(\omega t)u(t-t_0)\right)=e^{-s t_0}\int_{-t_0}^{\infty}e^{-s\tau}\sin(\omega(\tau +t_0))u(\tau)d\tau = e^{-s t_0}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-s\tau}\sin(\omega(\tau +t_0))d\tau 
$$

and finally as $\sin(a+b) = \sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b$

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\sin(\omega t)u(t-t_0)\right)=e^{-s t_0}\frac{s \sin (\omega  t_0)+\omega  \cos (\omega t_0)}{\omega ^2+s^2}
$$

NOTE

$$
\frac{s \sin (\omega  t_0)+\omega  \cos (\omega t_0)}{\sqrt{\omega ^2+s^2}} = \sin\left(\omega t_0+\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{s}\right)\right)
$$

so the answer can be written also as

$$
\mathcal{L}\left(\sin(\omega t)u(t-t_0)\right)=\frac{e^{-s t_0}}{\sqrt{\omega^2+s^2}}\sin\left(\omega t_0+\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{s}\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks. I have re-checked and made a few minor corrections to my solution after seeing your final answer but I still require the answer in arctan form as mentioned above. Also I was wondering how can we write $$\int_{-t_0}^{\infty}u(\tau)$$ as $$\int_{0}^{\infty}$$, what if $t_0=-3$ or any -ve value?

Comment: I got the final form:-) Just let me know the reasoning behind the integration limits as I have mentioned in my previous comment and that would be enough :-)

Comment: @paulplusx Remember that $u(t)$ is $0$ for $t < 0$ and $-t_0 < 0$ so the integration process goes from $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: @paulplusx Please. See also the note attached.

Comment: Like I have mentioned in my comments what would happen is $t_0<0$? Then $-t_0$ would be positive, right? Then the integral won't hold because it will start from 0 instead of $-t_0$(which is positive). Your argument will hold only for $t_0>0$

Comment: @paulplusx If $t_0 < 0$ then we could shift the time origin without problems in the Laplace transform.  All depends on the time origin for the Laplace operator.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not understanding it. Could you please use  a little maths to show what you mean? That would be really helpful.